# How do I make a JUnit Test Suite that runs tests conditionally based on a list of Test Classes?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

I need to make a JUnit test suite that runs tests based on an input file provided by the user. I.E if the user says that 5 of 10 tests should be run those 5 tests will be run and nothing more. Is there a way to take a list of Classes containing test my cases and run those only?
I tried to use  a for loop for this like so

```
for (Class a: classes)
    JUnitCore.runClasses(a);
```

but i got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/JUnitCore
at TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

Comment: The only thing i could think was to add an enhanced for loop that iterates over the classes like-
for (Class a : classes)
     JUnitCore.runClasses(a);
but that just gets me a classnotfound exception

Comment: I think, that's what the [Parameterized test runner](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Test-runners#parameterized) is for.

Comment: @ArtjomB. No, I don't think so.

Comment: Why should only those tests run? Are there something special about that particular subset?  Will the same subsets always be grouped together?

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternatives.

### Use Categories runner

It allows you to "tag" tests and construct test suite by tags. 
You can look in documentation:
https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories

Pros:

- easier to setup
- only tests marked with category will run

Cons:

- fixed test suites, to change them you have to change test code

### Use Rule

Write your on test rule and in this rule ignore (by throwing AssumptionViolatedException) all tests not in your list.
Documentation is here:

https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules

Look at TestWatcher rule, it has information about test class name and method name in Description object passed into its methods.

Pros:

- very flexible test suites

Cons:

- harder to setup
- all tests are run, but those not in list are ignored i.e. some @Before and @After methods may fire even when no tests are run
- all your tests must use this rule, test not using rule will run as usual